# Collecting terms from expression with indexed functions

Tags: summation, variable-definitions, index, indexed-variable

Say I have an expansion of terms containing functions `y[j,t]` and its derivatives, indexed by `j` with the index beginning at 0 whose independent variable are `t`, like so:

`Expr = y[0,t]^2 + D[y[0,t],t]*y[0,t] + y[0,t]*y[1,t] + y[0,t]*D[y[1,t],t] + (y[1,t])^2*y[0,t] +` ... etc.

Now I wish to define new functions indexed by `i`, call them `A[i]`, that collect all terms from the expression above such that the sum of the indices of the factors in each term sums to `i`.

In the above case for the terms shown we would have for example

`A[0] = y[0,t]^2 + D[y[0,t],t]*y[0,t]`

`A[1] = y[0,t]*y[1,t] + y[0,t]*D[y[1,t],t]`

`A[2] = (y[1,t])^2*y[0,t]`

How can I get mathematica to assign these terms to these new functions automatically for all `i`?

Note: If there is a better way to be indexing functions also feel free to suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the result in a list form for example as follows:

```
Reverse[MonomialList[Expr /. y[x_, z_] -> EPS^x*y[x, z] /. Derivative[A_, B_][y][x_, z_] -> EPS^x*Derivative[A, B][y][x, z], EPS]] /. EPS -> 1
```

> [image]

This replaces all instances of `y` or its derivatives by `EPS` to the power of first argument of the original `y` times itself. Then one can collect different monomials in `EPS` to a list and set the `EPS` back to `1` at the end.

Comment: I have a problem now, when I later on define y[0,t] say as `y[0,t_] = 1+2t` and then I recall the above elements of the list, the derivative `Derivative[0, 1][y][0, t]` will not evaluate with the new definition, it is left in its general form. How can I ensure that they are evaluated once the element of the list is called after I have defined y[0,t]?

Comment: @Decebalus if you define `y` to be an explicit function, this will break the routine that sorts the terms. I suggest, instead of locking in a definition, to use a substitution instead, whenever needed: `/. y :> (If[#1 === 0, 1 + 2 #2, y[#1, #2]] &)` -- This substitutes a function for each `y` where `#2` is the second argument of this function whenever the first argument `#1` is equal to `0`.

Comment: Thanks I will think about this, in the meantime would you mind having a look at this? [link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/201888/element-of-list-not-evaluating-derivative-after-i-define-function)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use [`Cases`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) to construct a function that computes the index-sum and use it with [`GatherBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GatherBy.html) to group the monomials:

```
ClearAll[f0, f1]
f0 = Total @* Cases[(y | Derivative[__][y])[i_, _]^p_. :> p i];
f1 = Total /@ GatherBy[SortBy[f0]@MonomialList[#], f0]&;

f1 @ Expr
```

> [image]