# Element of list not evaluating derivative after I define function

Tags: hold

I have the following code

```
Clear[AdomTrunctest, AdomPolyNtest, ListPolytest, y];
AdomTrunctest = 3;
ExDtest := Sum[D[y[n, t], t], {n, 0, AdomTrunctest}];
Ntest = Expand[(y'[t])^2 /. y'[t] -> ExDtest ];
ListPolytest = 
  Reverse[MonomialList[
     Ntest /. y[x_, z_] -> EPS^x*y[x, z] /. 
      Derivative[A_, B_][y][x_, z_] -> 
       EPS^x*Derivative[A, B][y][x, z], EPS]] /. EPS -> 1;
For[i = 0, i < AdomTrunctest + 1, i++, 
 AdomPolyNtest[i] = ListPolytest[[i + 1]]]
For[i = 0, i < AdomTrunctest + 1, i++, 
 Print["A", i, " = ", AdomPolyNtest[i]]]

 y[0, t_] = 1 + 2 t 

Print["A", 0, " = ", AdomPolyNtest[0]]
```

My issue is with the last few lines, if you run this code you will see the third last line prints the general form of the so called polynomials I am calculating, everything is good. However once I define `y[0, t_] = 1 + 2 t` in the second to last line, I expect now that once I call `AdomPolyNtest[0]` in the last line, that the derivative of `y[0,t]` be evaluated, and not left general, but it is instead left general. I believe this is because I have replaced `ExDtest` which was `SetDelayed`with `Derivative` within the `MonomialList` command, so it is no longer "evaluated afresh" each time it is called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After

```
Clear[AdomTrunctest, AdomPolyNtest, ListPolytest, y];
AdomTrunctest = 3;
ExDtest := Sum[D[y[n, t], t], {n, 0, AdomTrunctest}];
Ntest = Expand[(y'[t])^2 /. y'[t] -> ExDtest ];
ListPolytest = 
  Reverse[MonomialList[
     Ntest /. y[x_, z_] -> EPS^x*y[x, z] /. 
      Derivative[A_, B_][y][x_, z_] -> 
       EPS^x*Derivative[A, B][y][x, z], EPS]] /. EPS -> 1;
For[i = 0, i < AdomTrunctest + 1, i++, AdomPolyNtest[i] = ListPolytest[[i + 1]]]
For[i = 0, i < AdomTrunctest + 1, i++, Print["A", i, " = ", AdomPolyNtest[i]]]
```

instead of locking in an explicit expression for `y`, consider defining a substitution function such as

```
suby = { y :> (If[#1 === 0, 1 + 2 #2, y[#1, #2]] &) }
```

This will substitute the implicit function `1+2 #2` in place of `y` (where `#2` is the second argument of `y`) if the first argument of `y` is equal to `#1 === 0`:

```
Print["A", 0, " = ", AdomPolyNtest[0] /. suby]
```

> `A0 = 4`